# Is there a clean way to set up class autoloading when calling Phing to run a Propel 1 database migration?

Tags: php, migration, propel, bootstrapping

I'm using [migrations](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/10-migrations.html) in Propel 1, which works well enough. For some data operations I need access to the Propel class, and to a parent class for common migration methods, but since I am requesting the migration from Phing, this seems to be non-trivial.

I call the migration using this code:

```
php \
    /project/backend-app/vendor/phing/phing/bin/phing.php \
    -f /project/backend-app/vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build.xml \
    -Dusing.propel-gen=true \
    -Dproject.dir=/project/backend-app/db \
    -Dpropel.database.url='mysql:dbname=job_crawler_test;host=127.0.0.1' \
    -Dpropel.buildtime.conf.file='buildtime/job_crawler_test.xml' \
    -quiet \
    migrate
```

That works fine, as long as I have autoloading and initialisation code at the start of every class file that needs it:

```
$root = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../..');
require_once $root . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $root . '/lib/autoload.php';
set_include_path($root . '/lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
Propel::init($root . '/config/propel-conf.php');
```

OK, that works, but it's a bit messy - even though it's an official recommendation (see the bottom of the manual page link above). For cleanliness I'd like to strip this repetitive code block out.

I could of course just put this in a file and use a single `require` line in each file, which will reduce some of the cruft, but that's not very satisfying. I wonder if there's a `-D` flag I can pass to Phing, maybe like a bootstrap PHP file?

I wondered if `-Dphp.classpath` would do something, given that this seems to be [a Phing core property](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/app.factsheet.html#sec.builtinprops), but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You could use `-Dauto_prepend_file=` courtesy of PHP, if Phing allows such overrides.

Comment: Thanks @mario - gave it an optimistic try, to no avail. It seems the info about [available console params](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/sec.commandlineargs.html) is a bit sparse!

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean - add it to the `php` command - what a good idea. Trying that...

Comment: Nice one @mario, that's fixed it, with `php -d 'auto_prepend_file=/path/to/init.php' phing.php ...`. Would you be so kind as to put that in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mario made a kind suggestion in the comments, which fixed this issue flawlessly. I moved the autoload preamble to a separate script:

```
<?php

/*
 * db/scripts/propel-migration.php
 *
 * Bootstrap file for Propel migrations that need autoloading or access
 * to the Propel sub-system
 */

$root = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../..');
require_once $root . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $root . '/lib/autoload.php';
set_include_path($root . '/lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
\Propel::init($root . '/config/JobCrawler-conf.php');
```

I then modified the `php` call (i.e. rather than the `phing.php` call) thus:

```
php \
    -d 'auto_prepend_file=/project/backend-app/db/scripts/propel-migration.php' \
    <rest of call here>
```

The Propel migration classes now have full auto-loading and access to Propel's system without any pre-class boilerplate code.